# Why is it Ubuntu becomes no response when loading a large MAT file in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I do not know why Ubuntu becomes slow or even no response when I load a large MAT file (e.g., 1GB) in Matlab?

My Ubuntu is 14.04 and the PC has 8GB RAM.

Comment: Do you need to load the entire MAT file? If not, things might go more smoothly if you only load the variables you need. http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/load-parts-of-variables-from-mat-files.html

Comment: Hi @eigenchris , thanks! Yes, I need to open the entire MAT file. The problem is when I was opening the file, the mouse does not move anymore until it finished. And then when I running the code, the MATLAB process was killed by Ubuntu, which did not happen on OS X. Could you please advise me if there is any solution to this? Thanks!

Comment: I'm afraid I can't say. I've never dealt with MAT files anywhere near that size.

Answer (score 0):

Run `memory` at the command line to see what the capabilities of the system that freezes is, versus the one that doesn't.  The important values are "Maximum possible array" and "Memory available for all arrays.", and are generally quite a bit lower than the available RAM.

These may vary depending on your version of MATLAB (particularly 32 vs. 64 bit - including 32 bit MATLAB running on a 64 bit system).

In addition, there is some compression in *.mat files (Version 7 onwards). Therefore, it may be that the file is 1GB but would require more than 1GB memory to fully read in.  You can use `matfile` to examine the sizes of variables in the file.